# Trigger Azure Data Factory on a specific date avoiding WEEKEND

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data Factory pipeline which needs to trigger on the 25th of each month.

However, if the 25th falls on a weekend day (Saturday and Sunday) then the trigger should run on the Friday before the weekend.

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

We will have to create a two triggers

TRG1 1 : With the below Schedule object . read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger#examples-of-trigger-recurrence-schedules)

```
        "schedule": { "weekDays":["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday"],
            "monthDays": [
                25
            ]
        }
```

TRG 2

```
        "schedule": { "weekDays":["friday"],
            "monthDays": [
                24
            ]
        }
```